# Zipping two lists with an offset in Python

Tags: python, beginner, iterator

Walking my first steps in Python from C, I find myself missing pointers from time to time.

In this case I want to go through a list processing two element at a time, where those elements are *step* places away. This is my initial approach, but I would be happy to learn a couple alternatives, and their advantages.

```
v = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
step = 3
for x, y in zip( v[:-step], v[step:] ) :
  print("\nx={}, y={}".format(x, y))
```

I'm interested in what can be done with naked Python alone first. But alternatives from a module, are welcome as well. I want to know which approach is closer to pointer use in C (which was my intent with the code above) in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Just as an aside, your string formatting could be simplified as `print(f"\n{x=}, {y=}")` with modern f-strings.

Comment: Valuable tip. Makes it more readable. Thank you.

Comment: `print(f"\nx={x}, y={y}")` I assume

Comment: @Dronir No need to repeat what's already in an answer :-P. xcaliph: Why do you assume that? Our version works.

Comment: Maybe I too should have edited instead of commenting… xcaliph: `{x=}` is a shorthand for `x={x}`, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're on the right track, but it can be simplified to the following.
Note also that the `step` variable name could add confusion because Python [ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)
have a  step attribute -- but it's not what you are doing:

```
start = 3
for x, y in zip(v, v[start:]):
    ...
```

Also note that syntax like `v[start:]` creates a new list. If you are
dealing with large data volumes and want to avoid that, you can use
[itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
from itertools import islice

v = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

start = 3
for x, y in zip(v, islice(v, start, None)):
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @FMc 
Now I realize I was trying to make a view but in fact i was making a copy. I believe numpy arrays do use views when slicing, hence my confusion.
Also, I see that zip does no need for the lists to be equal lenth which I somehow asumed.

The _islice_  suggestion seems very fit for my needs here too. 
If I were to use only python, do you think _buffer_ (or _memoryview_)  would be a good alternative ?

Comment: @xcaliph itertools _is_ only Python. That's like suggesting `stdbool.h` isn't C.

Comment: I've seen people not realizing how very inefficient such `islice` usage can be (like when you want to zip the first ten elements of a million-elements list with the last ten), so maybe point that out as well.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 . Yeah, you're right. Maybe you can understand it as a learning process. I'm getting used to the native tools first so I get a taste of the language. That way I'll feel the need for those standard modules that are really part of the core, as you say. Thank to your responses to a simple question, I'm getting  a better grasp than simply checking  the documentation.

Answer (score 13):

### Using `itertools.tee` to zip an iterable with itself

Since you are iterating twice on the same iterable, one possibility is to use `itertools.tee`:

```
from itertools import tee

def zip_offset(iterable, offset):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    for _ in range(offset):
        next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

print(list( zip_offset(range(10), 3) ))
# [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9)]
```

Using `tee` is particularly important if the iterable is an iterator. Consider:

```
from itertools import tee, islice

v = map(lambda x: 2*x, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a, b = tee(v)
print(list( zip(a, islice(b, 3, None)) ))
# [(0, 6), (2, 8), (4, 10), (6, 12), (8, 14), (10, 16), (12, 18)]

v = map(lambda x: 2*x, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(list( zip(v, islice(v, 3, None)) ))
# [(0, 8), (10, 12), (14, 16)]
```

### more_itertools.zip_offset

> Alternatives from a module are welcome as well

Meet [module `more_itertools` and its function `zip_offset`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.zip_offset):

```
from more_itertools import zip_offset

print(list( zip_offset('01234', 'abcdefghijkl', offsets=(0, 3)) ))
# [('0', 'd'), ('1', 'e'), ('2', 'f'), ('3', 'g'), ('4', 'h')]
```

You can look at [its source code](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#zip_offset):

```
from itertools import islice
from itertools import chain, repeat # used when negative offsets
from itertools import zip_longest   # used when longest=True

def zip_offset(*iterables, offsets, longest=False, fillvalue=None):
    if len(iterables) != len(offsets):
        raise ValueError("Number of iterables and offsets didn't match")
    staggered = []
    for it, n in zip(iterables, offsets):
        if n < 0:
            staggered.append(chain(repeat(fillvalue, -n), it))
        elif n > 0:
            staggered.append(islice(it, n, None))
        else:
            staggered.append(it)
    if longest:
        return zip_longest(*staggered, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    return zip(*staggered)
```

In the special case when the offset is 1, and assuming you're using python>=3.10, there is also `pairwise` in `itertools`:

```
from itertools import pairwise

print(list( pairwise('abcdef') ))
# [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know which approach is closer to pointer use in C in terms of efficiency

Pointers are very much not a thing in Python; and attempts to get toward them often end up in non-Pythonic code. @FMc's answer is a "correct and Pythonic" method, but is very much not like pointers. `zip` and `islice` are stateful iterators that carry context.

If I had to show code that would be the closest equivalent to pointers, it would be plain indexing:

```
v = range(10)

start = 3
for i in range(len(v) - start):
    x = v[i]
    y = v[i + start]
    print(x, y)
```

But again, unless you have a *really* good reason (and have eliminated all other options than micro-optimizing), don't do this.

Comment: If the rationale for an approach like this is efficiency/speed, two notes: (1) measure to confirm that it's actually faster (my assumption would be yes, but I've been surprised before on topics like this); and (2) remember that efficiency concerns are often relevant when data volumes are large, and under those conditions `len(v)` is sometimes (maybe often) unknown. Neither of those notes should be viewed as a criticism of the answer itself, which is valuable (+1).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indexing was in fact my very first approach. But as the goal was learning the tools of a new language, this seemed too much like camouflaged C for me. 
I was curious to learn both elegant and eficient ways to tackle a simple problem.

In my example, we are extracting data, but if we wanted to alter the list, for example, I think we'll find solutions similar to those that increase eficiency for this problem.

Comment: "don't do this"

Why? This code is much simpler and easier to understand than the higher-voted zip() based answers.

Comment: @NoahYetter I would offer that it's easier to understand for people who do not have a background in Python, particularly if their only experience is with C. However, it's straightforwardly non-Pythonic, and if the `zip` solution is difficult to understand for someone, that exposes a need for the developer in question to invest some learning into how Pythonic iteration works.

Answer (score 1):

Without offset, i.e., with `step = 0`, I'd expect the same results as for normal `zip`. But you produce *nothing*, because `v[:-step]` is empty then.

For negative offsets you *do* produce outputs, but I'd say rather not what one might want. For example for `v = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and `step = -3` you produce `(0, 7)`, `(1, 8)`, etc. Might be desirable to produce `(3, 0)`, `(4, 1)`, etc.

Your `print("\nx={}, y={}".format(x, y))` can be shortened: `print(f"{x=}, {y=}")` (same output, except I removed the leading newline which just caused extra empty lines which seemed pointless).

Comment: I find the f-string shortening suggestion from you and  @Dronir especially fit for auto debugging. I will use it from now on. At first I was confused cause my python enviroment wasn't fully updated. Very useful suggestion.